# Creating bar charts with binary data

Tags: ggplot2

I have the following data , which I am trying to use to create a bar chart from to show how preference of fruit varies with country:

[see data table here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqQE1.png)

I want to create a bar chart that shows preference of apples, oranges, grapes and bananas based on survey location (i.e x= surveyloc and Y = pref freq of oranges, apples, bananas). I am not quite sure how to do this when dealing with binary data and am hoping to get some assistance.

Comment: refer here'https://community.rstudio.com/t/trouble-with-bar-chart-binary-data/21376

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to see preference for multiple variables (ex. fruits) across multiple locations (ex. locations), when only having binary data ("yes" or "no", or 0 vs 1), a bar chart is probably not the best option.  My recommendation would be something like a tile plot so that you can convey at a glance preferences across the locations.  Here's an example using some dummy data.  I'll first show you an example of a bar plot (column plot), then the recommendation I have for you, which would be a tilemap.

#### Example Dataset

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(
  location = state.name[1:10],
  apples = rbinom(10,1,0.3),
  oranges = rbinom(10,1,0.1),
  pears = rbinom(10,1,0.25),
  grapes = rbinom(10,1,0.6),
  mangos = rbinom(10,1,0.65)
)

# tidy data
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = -location) %>%
  mutate(value = factor(value))
```

I created `df` above initially in the same format you have for your dataset (`location | pref1 | pref2 | pref3 | ...`).  It's difficult to use `ggplot2` to plot this type of data easily, since it is designed to handle what is referred to as [Tidy Data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  This is overall a better strategy for data management and is adaptable to whatever output you wish - I'd recommend reading that vignette for more info.  Needless to say, after the code above we have `df` formatted as a "tidy" table.

Note I've also turned the binary "value" column into a factor (since it only holds "0" or "1", and values of "0.5" and the like don't make sense here with this data).

#### "Bar Chart"

I put "bar chart" in quotes, because as we are plotting the value (0 or 1) on the y axis and location on the x axis, we are creating a "column chart".  "Bar charts" formally only need a list of values and plot count, density, or probability on the y axis.  Regardless, here's an example:

```
bar_plot <-
  df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=location, y=value, fill=name)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge", color='gray50', width=0.7) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d()
bar_plot
```

[image]

We could think about just showing where `value==1`, but that's probably not going to make things clearer.

#### Example of Tile Plot

What I think works better here is a tilemap.  The idea is that you spread `location` on the x axis and `name` (of the fruit) on the y axis, and then show the `value` field as the color of the resulting tiles.  I think it makes things a bit easier to view, and it should work pretty much the same if your data is binary or probabilistic.  For probability data, you just don't need to conver to a factor first.

```
tile_plot <-
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=location, y=name, fill=value)) +
  geom_tile(color='black') +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(`0`="gray90", `1`="skyblue")) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_x_discrete(expand=expansion(0)) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=expansion(0))
tile_plot
```

[image]

To explain a little what's going on here is that we setup the aesthetics as indicated above in `ggplot(...)`.  Then we draw the tiles with `geom_tile()`, where the `color=` represents the line around the tiles.  The actual fill colors are described in `scale_fill_manual()`.  The tiles are forced to be "sqare" via `coord_fixed()`, and then I remove excess area around the tiles via the `scale_x_*()` and `scale_y_*()` commands.